Getting the error when trying to bind():: invalid operands to binary expression ('basic_ostream<char, char_traits<char>>' and 'struct sockaddr_in')gcc
I am trying to print the return value for bind() that I am storing in x. However, I get the following error in VSCode:

invalid operands to binary expression ('basic_ostream<char, char_traits<char>>' and 'struct sockaddr_in')

How should I overcome this error?
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;
int main(){
    int serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    struct sockaddr_in serverAddress;
    serverAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverAddress.sin_port = htons(5555);
    serverAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    int lenaddr = sizeof(serverAddress);

    int x = bind(serverSocket, (struct sockaddr*)&serverAddress, sizeof(serverAddress));
    std::cout << "Print Bind Return Value -> " << x << std::endl;

    return 0;
}


A [mre] should be posted. There is no any string in the shown code.

What you have shown is not a [mcve] as it lacks the headers you are using. I'm guessing that the compiler is probably trying to call C++'s std::bind(), or some other version of bind(), instead of calling the socket library's ::bind() that you are expecting.

@RemyLebeau This is the complete code. I am unable to compile because I get the error mentioned in the description. Any pointers will be appreciated

@SoftwareFan What compiler are you using? Why are you using the C headers <stdio.h>, <stdlib.h>, and <cstring> at all? They don't belong in this code (and in most C++ code in general). More importantly, why are you using using namespace std;? That last one seems to be the root of your problem (which I eluded to earlier - the compiler is NOT calling the socket bind(), but is likely calling std::bind() instead). Get rid of using namespace std;, or use ::bind() instead.

Can't replicate: https://godbolt.org/z/5KTdr7T7T. This error seems to very depend on the build environment.

This is NOT the code that got the error you mentioned.  This code compiles fine.  YOU tried to print serverAddress, which is not a type that C++ natively knows how to print.
